# Disable intellisense for css classnames in .tsx/.ts files

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Whenever I enter a `.` after a object the autocomplete dropdown contains a lot of unnecessary css classnames as options:

[image]

Is it possible to ignore css files for ts/tsx intellisense, so i only get relevant options?

VS Code version: `1.37.1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.suggest.showClasses": false
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
  "editor.suggest.showClasses": false
}
```

Basically the same as Mark's answer but it looks like `"editor.suggest.filteredTypes"` has been deprecated since VSCode >= 1.40 in favor of settings like `"editor.suggest.showClasses"`.

Comment: do you have any evidence that it is deprecated? (like a link?)

Comment: @ysfaran They didn't do a good job of announcing but here's the [relevant Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83537) and [code change](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/0fd9a2ebb3fbdc93d8d87b3fd2b9dc164bf73b76) for VSCode >= 1.40

Comment: I managed to make it work by inserting these in my workspace config file but I was wondering where to put these so it becomes vscode's default behavior?

Comment: @crownlessking On windows open vscode and hit `Ctrl + Shift + P` and enter `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. Then just paste the above in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your settings:

```
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.suggest.filteredTypes": {
    "class": false,
  }
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
  "editor.suggest.filteredTypes": {
    "class": false,
  }
}
```

[it would be nice if you could combine these but `[typescript, typescriptreact]` didn't work for me.

From [types of completions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions) it looks like it is `class` that you want to filter out.

And see [create language-specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) to see how to create settings for specific languages.

You will have to reload vscode to see these changes take effect.